# Equivalent to tail -f for ls?

Tags: unix

I use `tail -f` all the time to have a Terminal display the contents of a log file; is there an equivalent way to have `ls` show you the real-time persistent view of a list of files in a directory?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how many entries we're talking about, this might be enough for you:

```
watch ls -l
```

Comment: This is perfect. The directory I was filtering has thousands of files, so I tweaked it to `watch ls -alh pattern*` to get `pattern1.txt`, `pattern2.txt`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
watch ls
```

`watch` is a very useful command that can be used with most other commands.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  Appreciate the snappy response.